# How to scale SVG without rewriting inner source code?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, svg, vuetify.js

In a Vue SFC, I have a prop called `svg` that contains string of SVG markup, `<svg>...</svg>`.

How do I draw and scale this?

Comment: It appears that the question changed significantly while I was writing my answer. I'm unclear how writing `{{svg}}` would draw an SVG, I would expect that to output the SVG's source code as text. Could you include a [mcve] to clarify the question?

Comment: @skirtle You are right. I tested my code by hard-coding `<svg>` tag instead of using `data()`, which was a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways to do it.

You could use `v-html`. That's a general-purpose way of injecting HTML strings into Vue templates. You would need to be sure that the source string is safe though, otherwise you'll be leaving yourself open to injection attacks.

Documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html

Another approach might be to use a `data:` URL, either as a `background-image` or as the `src` of an `<img>`.

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs

The example below illustrates both techniques:

```js
const DrawPicture = {
  template: `
    <div>
      <div v-html="svg"></div>
      <img :src="'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,' + encodeURIComponent(svg)">
    </div>
  `,
  
  props: ['svg']
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  components: {
    DrawPicture
  },
  
  data () {
    return {
      circle: `
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 80 80" width="80">
          <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="40" fill="#f00" />
        </svg>
      `
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <draw-picture :svg="circle"></draw-picture>
</div>
```

For the `data:` URL I've used `encodeURIComponent` to ensure the URL is escaped correctly. It is also possible to use `base64` with `btoa` instead.